# What does the Sold column in the Active Orders tab mean?

Tags: new-world

I don't quite understand how the active orders tab of items you are selling on the market works.  In particular, there is a "Sold" column, which for all of my active sell orders is the same quantity as the total quantity of the particular item I am trying to sell:

[image: active orders]

Is this a bug or am I misunderstanding this column somehow? To me, it would indicate that I have sold "X" amount of that item so far, but then why would it be in the Active Orders tab still and not in the Completed & Expired tab?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't been able to find any notes mentioned in official patch notes, but I believe the [Winter Convergence event/update](https://www.newworld.com/en-us/game/releases/december-update-winter-convergence) addressed this (since this was the first update after posting this question), as the column now seems to correctly show the amount sold so far for the orders.  Thus, this appears to have been a bug that has been fixed.